# CSS PIE working on one computer but not on another (same browser)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to use a CSS Pie.htc for my website. However a strange thing happens... the CSS pie is working on a computer but not on another, even though the browser is the same (IE 8.0.6001.18702).

I tried to write the behavior in my selectors in several ways, eg

```
behavior: url (PIE.htc)
behavior: url ('PIE.htc')
behavior: url(PIE.htc)
behavior: url('http://mysite.com/PIE.htc')
```

And I can't figure it out. The PIE.htc file is in the parent  root of the website.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to view [developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE; is the Browser Mode set the same on both machines?

Comment: Yes, the Browser mode are the same (Browser Mode: IE8 File mode: standard IE8). However I think it is a problem of the browser, since neither the css-pie website is rendered well. But I cannot understand which IE function is disabling pie.

Answer (score 0):

Check IE's security settings on the computer that PIE works on, and then compare to the one that it doesn't work on. It could be that there are certain security settings on the one machine that are preventing PIE from executing.